# Get id from path in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

So I have this SVG

https://github.com/Cphdat3sem2017f/StartcodeExercises/blob/master/JS/Countries_Europe.svg?short_path=6bcbfa5

I managed to hook up an eventListener and a fetch to get information on the countries when clicked on. This I have done by simply calling ex. document.getElementById("dk"). Is there a way and if so how, where i can get the id's inside the paths so I can loop through them and end up with only one call instead of one for each country?

Code:

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");

const country = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha?codes=";

svg.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;

  var countries = svgDoc.children;
  for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    //alert(countries[i].id);
    countries[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      alert(countires[i]);
      getCountryInfo(countries[i].id);
    });
  }

  svgDoc.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    getCountryInfo(event.id);
  });

  var denmark = svgDoc.getElementById("dk");
  denmark.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("dk");
  });

  var sweden = svgDoc.getElementById("se");
  sweden.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("se");
  });

  var germany = svgDoc.getElementById("de");
  germany.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("de");
  });

  var norway = svgDoc.getElementById("no");
  norway.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("no");
  });

  var spain = svgDoc.getElementById("es");
  spain.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("es");
  });

  var iceland = svgDoc.getElementById("is");
  iceland.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getCountryInfo("is");
  });
});

function getCountryInfo(landCode) {
  fetch(country + landCode)
    .then(res => res.json()) //.then(res=>{ return res.json()})
    .then(data => {
      var table = "";
      table +=
        '<table border="1" style="border-spacing: 5px; table-layout: auto; width: 45%;">';
      table += "<tr>";
      table += "<th>Name</th>";
      table += "<th>Capital</th>";
      table += "<th>Also known as</th>";
      table += "<th>Region</th>";
      table += "<th>Population</th>";
      table += "<th>Languages</th>";
      table += "</tr>";
      data.forEach(country => {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td>" + country.name + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + country.capital + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + country.altSpellings + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + country.region + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + country.population + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + country.languages + "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";
      });
      table += "</table>";
      root.innerHTML = table;
    });
}
```

As you can see we tried to get them by getting the children elements but we got stuck and couldn't seem to find answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `children` resolves to in that context, but you can get to the paths directly via a query:

```
[...svgDoc.querySelectorAll('path')].forEach(path => {
    path.addEventListener('click', e => {
        alert(path.id);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that worked, we weren't certain about the children but that was what we thought we had heard from earlier. Thanks for the help!