# How to retrieve the id of a g element within an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG file and inside I have some groups `<g id="example-1">... </g>.`

I have code that works fine in jQuery. But I can't do it with pure javascript.

With jQuery it works like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('svg g').on("click", function(e){
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
         console.log(`Clicked in ${this.id}`);
      });
   });
```

Comment: I found this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053433/13649080](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053433/13649080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a question I can answer without using Web Components

```js
  document.querySelectorAll("svg").forEach(svg => {
    svg.querySelectorAll("g").forEach(group => {
      group.onclick = (evt) => {
        svg.activegroup?.classList.remove("active");
        (svg.activegroup = group).classList.add("active");
        console.log("clicked group:", group.id);
      }
    });
  });
```